# Can I spead empty array in JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I receive this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '...'` when I am running the following code

```
[1,2,3, (true ? 4 : ...[])]
```

is it possible to spread an empty array like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to spread the expression, but you can not spread an array as single expression.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, ...(true ? [4] : [])];

console.log(array);
```